# Getting Conversion failed error when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my table values are saved as `Thursday November 12, 2020  07:01`.  I want to convert those values to the date time. This is the query which I wrote.

```
select  
 convert(varchar(200), replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(publishedon,'Monday',''),'Saturday',''),'Sunday',''),'Tuesday',''),'Wednesday',''),'Thursday',''),'Friday','')) 
from py_EconNext
```

Once I removed the days from the values, I can get values as `November 12, 2020  11:04`. After that I try to convert it to datetime. When converting this to the datetime, I’m getting the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

But when I run  select as below

```
select  convert(datetime,convert(varchar(200),(' November 12, 2020  11:04')))
```

I can get the values as `2020-11-12 11:04:00.000` without any error.

Table column  datatype  - varchar(200)

Comment: You fell victim to one of the [classic blunders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWW6aDpUvbQ) - the most famous of which is "never get involved in a land war in Asia" - but only slightly less well-known is this: "Never put dates in a column with varchar as the type!"

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn You just love that quote and movie!

Comment: @SMor I do. :) It's also easier to copy/paste the same thing each time, and humor helps soften the blow when you need to tell someone they did it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing datetime in varchar column is bad idea.Use appropriate column type when storing data.

Considering your question i assume there is invalid characters included in data like CR, LF or CR+LF.

try to replace them by

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

Comment: yes, it getting an error because of the special characters include in the string. After the replace it getting worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have inconsistent styles of a date, that is (foolishly) being stored as a `varchar`. This is why storing dates as a `varchar` is **always** a bad idea. The *real* solution is fix your design.

You can get around this with a couple of `TRY_CONVERT`s, **provided** that your style is *always* `mon dd, yyyy hh:mi:ss` or `day, mon dd, yyyy hh:mi:ss`. I am using  the style code `109` to be explicit on the style code `mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM (or PM)` (note that it is happy to accept a 24 clock too):

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(datetime,V.YourString,109),TRY_CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(V.YourString,1,CHARINDEX(' ',V.YourString),''),109))
FROM (VALUES('Thursday November 12, 2020 17:01'),('Thursday November 12, 2020 07:01'),('November 12, 2020 07:01'))V(YourString)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than converting into a `VARCHAR` (which it already is), it would make more sense to convert straight into a `DATETIME`.

As well as that, there is no need to have all the embedded `REPLACE` statements - just take all of the text from the string after the first space.

Try this code:

```
CREATE TABLE #py_EconNext (publishedon VARCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO #py_econNext VALUES ('Thursday November 12, 2020 07:01');

select convert(datetime, RIGHT(publishedon, LEN(publishedon) - CHARINDEX(' ', publishedon))) 
 from #py_EconNext;

DROP TABLE #py_EconNext;
```

Output:

```
2020-11-12 07:01:00.000
```

**Edit following suggestion to use `TRY_CONVERT`**

Following a helpful comment suggesting the use of `TRY_CONVERT` in place of `CONVERT`, please see the equivalent code using the other function:

```
CREATE TABLE #py_EconNext (publishedon VARCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO #py_econNext VALUES ('Thursday November 12, 2020 07:01'),('Not valid');

select try_convert(datetime, RIGHT(publishedon, LEN(publishedon) - CHARINDEX(' ', publishedon))) 
 from #py_EconNext 

DROP TABLE #py_EconNext;
```

Output:

```
2020-11-12 07:01:00.000
NULL
```

This benefits from not causing an error if the conversion fails, but rather returns `NULL`.

My personal view is that a data conversion failure is an error and should be treated as such, but the desired solution would ultimately be dictated by the use case OP is outlining.

Comment: I suspect OP has bogus data.  This would still throw an error.  Use try_convert()

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Should it not throw an error if the data doesn't match the requirement?  It works on the data as OP has indicated it is formatted

Comment: At least a bogus value could be identified and parked as a NULL until it can be resolved

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thank you for the suggestion in that case.  I've amended the answer to provide either solution